# what the parameters efg and _nc_cat mean?

Tags: facebook, http, query-string, devtools, har

I am debugging the videos of Facebook with Google DevTools and I have extracted this URL from a session:

https://video-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-2/53550305_2358483951072946_193896070944653312_n.mp4?_nc_cat=101&efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImRhc2hfdjRfaHExX2ZyYWdfMl92aWRlbyJ9&_nc_ht=video-mad1-1.xx&oh=488644f30a2a36fc4650ba77c9ab81ce&oe=5C9926CF&bytestart=0&byteend=993

I have all parameters but I haven't idea what mean the parameter efg and parameter _nc_cat, which I have seen that they change with respect with the following streams.

Comment: Most likely some form of token, that limits the validity of the URL.

Comment: There are more streams which have _nc_cat=1, other with the value of 110 and I had thought that these parameters were related with the quality of the stream